# Mist pass issue with Megascans plants assets

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have an problem with Megascan plants assets not behaving correctly with the mist pass.
It works with other plant assets (graswald, polygoniq, etc...).
I cranked up the transparent and transmission sample count up to 1000+, no difference.

The alpha texture map seems ok.

I'm missing something?

[image]